nextjs - Función Get para obtener datos
En mi aplicación nextJs estoy tratando que se muestre toda la información que un usuario lleno aparezca en una pagina, el problema que tengo principalmente es que, al parecer en dentro de api/historial/ en la función GET no esta buscando al usuario, pero si fuera "normal"(es decir, que se esten mostrando todos los registros) si esta funcionando.
Para objecto de pruebas estoy intentando que en la URL (http://localhost:3000/api/historial/id de la base de datos de algun registro) lo busque y lo muestre, pero no esta haciendolo, solo me da error 400 o 500, aqui la función GET dentro de /api/historial/route.js
import clientPromise from "@/libs/mongodb";
import  Historial from "@/models/historial";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
    export const GET = async(req, {params}) => {
        //Conexion a la base de datos
        const client = await clientPromise;
        const db = client.db();
    
        const { id } = req.params;
        const historial = await db.collection("historial").findOne({_id: ObjectId(id)}).toArray();
        //console.log(historial);
        return NextResponse.json({ historial });
    }

De igual forma muestro de donde y como se debe ver los datos que traiga de la base de datos
 "use client" import { Footer, NavbarSignOut} from "@/components";
 import Link from "next/link" import { getServerSession } from
 "next-auth"; import { redirect, usePathname, useSearchParams} from
 "next/navigation"; import CustomButton from
 '../../../components/CustomButton'; import {useSession} from
 'next-auth/react'; //import MyListbox from "@/components/listboxHijo";
 import InputNumber from "@/components/InputNumber"; import React,
 {useEffect, useState} from "react"; import { useRouter } from
 "next/navigation"; //import React, {useState} from "react";
 
 
 const HistorialV = () => {
     const router= useRouter();
     const searchParams = useSearchParams();
     const nombre = searchParams.get("nombre");
     console.log(searchParams.get("nombre"));
     

     return (
         <>
             <main className="formUser">
                 {/*contenedor del formulario*/}
                 <div className="bg-[#FFEBA9] rounded-lg"> 
                     <div className="flex flex-col rounded-lg">                 
                         <div className="items-start px-[50px] py-[10px]"><br />
                             <div className="flex justify-end"><Link href="/terapeuta" className="hover:text-[#E55E7F] font-extrabold
 text-[22px]">Salir</Link></div>
                             <h1 className="formUserTitle">Historial clínico de {nombre}</h1>
                             <p>Historial clinico del Paciente Seleccionado</p> 
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div className="formUserDiv"> 
                         <div className="formUserDiv"> 
                             {/*titulo e instrucciones */}
                             <div className="formUserForm"><br />
                                 <form className=" w-full pl-4" method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                     <h3 className="formUserSubtitle">Datos generales</h3> 
                                 
                                     <div className="formUserDiv mt-[20px] pl-[30px]">
                                         <div className="mb-4">
                                             <p className="formUserText">Telefono</p>
                                             <input name="telefono" onChange={handleChange} value={''} id="telefono" type="number"
 className="outline-none text-base pl-2 border-gray-300 rounded-lg py-2
 px-4" readOnly/>
                                         </div>
                                         <div className="edad">
                                             <p className="formUserText">Edad</p>
                                             <input name="edad" onChange={handleChange}  id="edad" value={''}  type="number"
 className="inputBox" readOnly/>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
 
                                     <div className="formUserDiv mt-[20px] pl-[30px]">
                                         <div className="mb-4">
                                             <p className="formUserText">Estado Civil</p>
                                             
                                             <div className="radio"> 
                                                 <div className="mr-4">
                                                     <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value="" id="casado" name="estadoCivil" 
 className="inputBox" readOnly/>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>      
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
 
                                     <h3 className="formUserSubtitle">Datos familiares</h3>
                                     <div className="formUserDiv pt-[10px]">
                                         <div className="w-full pl-[30px]"><p className="formUserText">Padres Fallecidos</p></div>
                                         
                                         <div className="flex flex-row pl-[30px] gap-[10px]">
                                             <input type="text" name="papas" id="papas" className="inputBox" readOnly/>
                                         </div>
                                     </div><br/>
 
                                     <div className="w-full pl-[30px] gap-[40px]">
                                         <p className="formUserText">Número de hijo</p>
                                         <p className="formUserWarning">*Incluyendo abortos dentro de la
 familia*</p><br />
                                         <input name="noHijo" onChange={handleChange}  id="noHijo" value={''} required={true}
 type="number"  className="inputBox" readOnly/>
                                         {/* <InputNumber/>*/} <br/><br/> {/*value={formData.noHijo}*/}
                                         
                                             
                                         <p className="formUserText">Hijos Propios</p>
                                         <p className="formUserWarning">*Incluyendo abortos que conozca dentro de
 la familia*</p><br />
                                         <input name="hijoPropio" onChange={handleChange}  id="hijoPropio" value={''}  type="number" 
 className="inputBox" readOnly/>
                                         
                                     </div>
 
                                     <h3 className="formUserSubtitle">Datos médicos</h3> 
                                     <div className="w-full pl-[30px] gap-[40px]">{/**/}
                                         <p className="formUserText">Operaciones del Paciente</p>
                                             
                                         <textarea  name="operaciones" onChange={handleChange} required={true} value={''} id="operaciones"   
                                         className="flex w-full inputBox resize-none bg-white h-[170px] whitespace-normal break-words
 pt-2" readOnly></textarea> {/*value={formData.operaciones} */}
                                         <br /><br />
 
                                             <p className="formUserText">Medicamentos</p>
                                                 <div className="flex flex-row  gap-[10px]"> 
                                                     
                                                 </div>
                                             <textarea  name="medicamentos"  value={''} onChange={handleChange}
 id="medicamentos"   
                                             className="flex w-full inputBox resize-none bg-white h-[170px] whitespace-normal break-words
 pt-2" readOnly></textarea> {/*value={formData.operaciones} */}
                                             <br /><br />
                                     </div>
                                     <Link href="/terapeuta"><CustomButton
                                         btnType="submit"
                                         title="Salir"
                                         containerStyles="text-white rounded-lg bg-pink-400 min-w-[100px] font-medium textButton mt-5
 hover:bg-[#E55E7F] h-10"
                                     /> </Link>
                                     
 
                                 </form>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
 
                 </div>
                 <br/><br/><br/>
             </main>
             
         </>
     ); };

 export default HistorialV;

